# Java/Spring: How to specify order for nested transactions with TransactionSynchronizationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, events, transactions

I have some logic that needs to execute after the transaction commits so I am using something like below:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization() {
                @Override
                public void afterCommit() {
                    //do work
                }
            });
```

And this works fine. My question is if I register multiple handler like these in a nested transaction, is the order guaranteed to be in the registration order? So for example:

```
class Obj1 {
   @Transactional
   public void doTX1() {
      //invoke another method that is marked as transactional
      obj2.doInnerTx();

      TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization() {
                    @Override
                    public void afterCommit() {
                        System.out.println("Outer TX");
                    }
                });
   }
}

 class Obj2 {
       @Transactional
       public void doInnerTx() {
          TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization() {
                        @Override
                        public void afterCommit() {
                            System.out.println("Inner TX");
                        }
                    });
       }
    }
```

Output:

```
Inner TX
Outer TX
```

But is this guaranteed? If not, how would I enforce the order such that inner one always gets executed first ?

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc of the registerSynchronization() method says:

```
Note that synchronizations can implement the
     * {@link org.springframework.core.Ordered} interface.
     * They will be executed in an order according to their order value (if any)
```

If you use new `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {..}` instead of `new TransactionSynchronization() {..}` you can override the `getOrder()` method along with `afterCommit()` since `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` already implements `Ordered interface`. From the javadoc:

```
The default * {@link #getOrder() order} is 
{@link Ordered#LOWEST_PRECEDENCE}, indicating * late execution; return a lower 
value for earlier execution.
```

Lowest precedence value is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`